# Is the expression "a==1 ? 1 : 0" with comparison plus ternary operator expression atomic?

Tags: java, c++, pthreads, atomic

Quick question? Is this line atomic in C++ and Java?

```
class foo {
  bool test() {
    // Is this line atomic?
    return a==1 ? 1 : 0;
  }

  int a;
}
```

If there are multiple thread accessing that line, we could end up with doing the check
a==1 first, then a is updated, then return, right?

Added: I didn't complete the class and of course, there are other parts which update a...

Comment: Your code does not update `a` at all, therefore there are no data races.

Comment: Then you should say there is no code at all, as test() cannot be called.

Comment: "I didn't complete the class and of course, there are other parts which update a" Then the displayed code is not sufficient to determine the existence of data races. If the code you don't show fails to do proper synchronization then there is a datarace and the code has undefined behavior in C++.

Comment: Please update your question and put more codes. It doesn't show your code flow, so deciding whether its atomic or not is not possible.

Answer (score 8):

No, for both C++ and Java.

In Java, you need to make your method `synchronized` and protect other uses of `a` in the same way. Make sure you're synchronizing on the same object in all cases.

In C++, you need to use [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to protect `a`, probably using [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to make sure you properly unlock the mutex at the end of your function.

Comment: `a` is not updated in any way, so why would `synchronized` help?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Theoretically there's more to this class, but yeah, there could be other synchronization issues.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson there is no code at all, as test() cannot be called. Why did you not mentioned that?

Comment: `AtomicBoolean`? The possible race condition is not with a boolean, but rather with an integer value

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm taking a somewhat wild guess at what he's trying to get at, but yes, I could be way off.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks for pointing this out, I thought he was trying to create some sort of test and set sort of thing, but I think that turned out to be more confusing than anything else. I've removed that part.

Answer (score 7):

```
return a==1 ? 1 : 0;
```

is a simple way of writing

```
if(a == 1)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

I don't see any code for updating a. But I think you could figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of whether there is a write, reading the value of a non-atomic type in C++ is **not** an atomic operation. If there are no writes then you might not care whether it's atomic; if some other thread might be modifying the value then you certainly do care.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of putting it is simply: No! (both for Java and C++)

A less correct, but more practical answer is: Technically this is not atomic, but on most mainstream architectures, it is at least for C++.

Nothing is being modified in the code you posted, the variable is only tested. The code will thus usually result in a single `TEST` (or similar) instruction accessing that memory location, and that is, incidentially, atomic. The instruction will read a cache line, and there will be one well-defined value in the respective loaction, whatever it may be.

However, this is incidential/accidential, not something you can rely on.

It will usually even work -- again, incidentially/accidentially -- when a single other thread writes to the value. For this, the CPU fetches a cache line, overwrites the location for the respective address within the cache line, and writes back the entire cache line to RAM. When you test the variable, you fetch a cache line which contains either the old or the new value (nothing in between). No happens-before guarantees of any kind, but you can still consider this "atomic".

It is much more complicated when several threads *modify* that variable concurrently (not part of the question). For this to work properly, you need to use something from C++11 `<atomic>`, or use an atomic intrinsic, or something similar. Otherwise it is very much unclear what happens, and what the result of an operation may be -- one thread might read the value, increment it and write it back, but another one might read the original value before the modified value is written back.
This is more or less guaranteed to end badly, on all current platforms.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not atomic (in general) although it can be in some architectures (in C++, for example, in intel  if the integer is aligned which it will be unless you force it not to be).

Consider these three threads:

```
// thread one:                // thread two:             //thread three
while (true)                  while (true)               while (a) ;
   a = 0xFFFF0000;               a = 0x0000FFFF;
```

If the write to `a` is not atomic (for example, intel if `a` is unaligned, and for the sake of discussion with 16bits in each one of two consecutive cache lines). Now while it seems that the third thread cannot ever come out of the loop (the two possible values of `a` are both non-zero), the fact is that the assignments are not atomic, thread two could update the higher 16bits to be 0, and thread three could read the lower 16bits to be 0 before thread two gets the time to complete the update, and come out of the loop.

The whole conditional is irrelevant to the question, since the returned value is local to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

No, it still a test followed by a set and then a return.

Yes, multithreadedness will be a problem.

It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: There is no "set" (i.e. no write) in the code posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be rephrased as: is statement:

```
   a == 1
```

atomic or not? No it is not atomic, you should use std::atomic for a or check that condition under lock of some sort. If whole ternary operator atomic or not does not matter in this context as it does not change anything. If you mean in your question if in this code:

```
bool flag = somefoo.test();
```

flag to be consistent to a == 1, it would definitely not, and it irrelevant if whole ternary operator in your question is atomic.

Comment: Is `a == 1` atomic, that depends on the type of `a`, and the underlying architecture. It might be.

Comment: @Liosan From C++ point of view it is not atomic. If it can be used on some platforms? yes. But then question should mention particular platform and other conditions.

Comment: Well, OK, good point @Slava. It also depends on other factors, like alignment.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of good answers here, but none of them mention the need in Java to mark `a` as `volatile`.

This is *especially* important if no other synchronization method is employed, but other threads could updating `a`. Otherwise, you could be reading an old value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
bool done = false;

void Thread1() {
  while (!done) {
    do_something_useful_in_a_loop_1();
  } 
  do_thread1_cleanup();
}

void Thread2() {
  do_something_useful_2();
  done = true;
  do_thread2_cleanup();
}
```

The synchronization between these two threads is done using a boolean variable done. This is a wrong way to synchronize two threads.

On x86, the biggest issue is the compile-time optimizations.

Part of the code of do_something_useful_2() can be moved below "done = true" by the compiler.
Part of the code of do_thread2_cleanup() can be moved above "done = true" by the compiler.
If do_something_useful_in_a_loop_1() doesn't modify "done", the compiler may re-write Thread1 in the following way:

```
  if (!done) {
    while(true) {
      do_something_useful_in_a_loop_1();
    } 
  }
  do_thread1_cleanup();
```

so Thread1 will never exit.

On architectures other than x86, the cache effects or out-of-order instruction execution may lead to other subtle problems.

Most race detector will detect such race.

Also, most dynamic race detectors will report data races on the memory accesses that were intended to be synchronized with this bool

(i.e. between do_something_useful_2() and do_thread1_cleanup())

To fix such race you need to use compiler and/or memory barriers (if you are not an expert -- simply use locks).